# Arithmetic operations in for loop

Tags: shell

I have a C++ code which I want to convert into POSIX sh code:

```c
for(int j=(i-(i%9)); j<((i-(i%9))+9); j++)
{
    ...
}
```

My question is that how can I convert this for lopp into POSIX shell?
This doesn't work:

```sh
for j in {{$i-($i%9)..{($i-(i%9)+9)}}
do
    echo $j;
done
```

Comment: Don't include images in your code -- copy/paste actual text. That way StackOverflow's own syntax highlighting can work, and people using screen-readers or text-based browsers can actually read your question (and, moreover, the question stays usable even if the link to your image breaks).

Comment: ...also, even with numbers hardcoded, `{{1..9}}`-type brace expansions are a bashism, not guaranteed to be available in `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your shell is `/bin/bash` (as the question initially indicated), with far fewer changes than you think you need, since [bash supports C-style `for` loops](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for). A more compressed syntax is possible with some releases, but to be safe across parser versions, being generous with whitespace is well-advised:

```
for (( j = ( i - ( i % 9) ); j < ( ( i - ( i % 9 ) ) + 9 ); j++ )); do echo "$j"; done
```

---

With `/bin/sh`, by contrast:

```
j=$(( i - ( i % 9 ) ))
while [ "$j" -lt "$(( ( i - ( i % 9 ) ) + 9 ))" ]; do
  echo "$j"
  j=$(( j + 1 ))
done
```

---

As for your original attempt, brace expansions happen very early in the parsing process -- before any variables' values have been evaluated; consequently, they can't be used with any numbers that aren't static.

Comment: Getting an unexpected EOF ")" http://prntscr.com/9231r7

Comment: Is your shell actually bash? If it's `#!/bin/sh`, that's a different shell.

Comment: Also, don't use image links: I can't copy/paste from them to test, and any retyping has room to introduce errors.

Comment: Yes it is #!/bin/sh style

Comment: If your question is about `/bin/sh`, not `bash`, edit your question to no longer say `bash`.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry edited